# Changing Related Item View lookup source

Tags: 2010

I changed the default lookup field to a custom made autocomplete lookup field.

https://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/

With that, the Related Item View stops working. Is there a way to bind it with the new lookup field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a hidden default lookup field. And using a workflow to set the value of the default lookup field to the same of the custom one.